# Детектив — это жанр?

Tags: терминология

Один человек несколько раз поправлял меня: «Детектив, хоррор и т.д. — это не жанр, а издательский ярлык для удобства продаж читателям. Жанр — это роман, и точка».
Правильно ли он говорит?
Я вот думаю, что роман — это форма. Сайты вроде "фантлаб" тоже делят романы по жанрам. Мой друг ошибается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я далеко не ходил, почитал Википедию.

> Литерату́рные жа́нры (фр. genre, от лат. genus — род, вид) — исторически складывающиеся группы литературных произведений, объединённых совокупностью формальных и содержательных свойств (в отличие от литературных форм, выделение которых основано только на формальных признаках)

-

> Рома́н — литературный жанр

Детекти́в — тоже литературный жанр.

> Детекти́в  (от лат. detectio — раскрытие, англ. detect — открывать, обнаруживать; detective — сыщик) — преимущественно литературный и кинематографический **жанр**, произведения которого описывают процесс исследования загадочного происшествия с целью выяснения его обстоятельств и раскрытия загадки. Обычно в качестве такого происшествия выступает преступление, и детектив описывает его расследование и определение виновных, в таком случае конфликт строится на столкновении справедливости с беззаконием, завершающемся победой справедливости.

-

> Литературное произведение может быть причислено к тому или иному жанру по различным критериям

Как я понимаю, жанры могут пересекаться, например есть детективные романы и детективные рассказы.

Answer (score 1):

Жанр  — это общее понятие.

ЖАНР,  [франц. genre] 1. Исторически сложившийся род **искусства или литературы,** характеризующийся определёнными сюжетными, композиционными, стилистическими и др. признаками; отдельные **разновидности этого рода**.

В художественной литературе выделяется фольклор (устное народное творчество) и литература. У фольклора свои жанры (эпические, лирические, драматические), а литература делится **на роды и жанры**. Существуют три основных рода: **эпос, лирика, драма**. Каждый род — это группа жанров.

Роман — эпический жанр, как и рассказ. Но роман относится к группе больших эпических жанров, а рассказ — к группе малых эпических жанров.

**Можно ли роман разделить на жанры? Я думаю, что да.**

Ведь названия эти **условны**: жанр определяется как род, род делится на жанры, среди которых можно выделить свои разновидности. Все эти системные единицы (роды и жанры) характеризуются какими-то особенностями, что позволяет делить их на группы или, напротив, объединять.

**Можно даже пойти в обратную сторону** и сказать, что литература — это множество жанров, и детективный роман — один из них. Далее детективные романы отнесем к романам, далее к большому эпическому жанру, далее просто к эпическому жанру (эпосу), а эпос — это уже род литературы.